# How do I allow public/unauthenticated publish to my GCP pub/sub topic from front-end webapp?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-iam

After reading a guide on GCP PubSub, I've created a new topic which pushes data into BigQuery. That part is working fine.

What's not working is: I still need to be authenticated to publish to the topic. Even though I have added the `allUsers` principal with `Pub/Sub Publisher` role. Infact, it even shows a big scary warning saying:

> This resource is public and can be accessed by anyone on the internet. To remove public access, remove "allUsers" and "allAuthenticatedUsers" from the resource's principals.

Despite this, when I try to send a POST request to the HTTP endpoint, it still demands auth.

```
POST https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{my-project}/topics/{my-topic}:publish

HTTP Status=403
"message": "The request is missing a valid API key."
```

Well of course it's missing an API key: it's supposed to be public!

I realize there are some workarounds: create a service user, implement bearer auth on front-end. Or proxy this through a CloudFunction. But those have major drawbacks in terms of added complexity and/or cost. It seems there must be some trivial way to handle this.

For context: This is probably an X/Y problem. My usecase is to push arbitrary blobs of data from a web front-end, and have them end up in BigQuery in near-realtime. Not unlike how Google Analytics allows a web front-end to send "events" which then appear in the Analytics web UI after ~24h. Unfortunately, a large portion of my users are running adblockers, which break Google Analytics, impeding our ability to understand how users engage with our webapp. Googling around led me to [this marketing pitch about how PubSub is great for streaming analytics into BigQuery with low cost](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/pub-sub-launches-direct-path-to-bigquery-for-streaming-analytics). But if I have to run my own microservice to proxy these inbound requests anyway, then PubSub adds no value as I can then stream the data directly to BigQuery. So there must be something I'm missing. Maybe there's another GCP service better suited for this usecase?

Comment: Unless you have infinite funds, do not allow unauthenticated access. You will be abused. Rethink your approach to security and authorization. Some websites publish unsecured endpoints. Hackers will attack just for the experience.

Answer (score 2):

The API key is not used for authentication with Pub/Sub; it is used for attributing quota. Therefore, you still need to attach an API Key to the request, even though you have allowed `allUsers` to access the topic. You would have to [create the API key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#create) and then attach it to all requests with the `key=<api key>` query parameter.

However, as John Hanley mentions, this is still risky as it means anyone will be able to publish arbitrary data into your topic, even data that doesn't represent actual traffic to your site. This can be a concern with analytics in general, however, it is even more of a concern if you are going to be paying for all of the data transmitting through Cloud Pub/Sub.